# Removing the same character from the middle of a string in Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcgis

This is the String I have in one column; CO060020N0650W0.  I need it to say 2N65W.

The second character is '5', sometimes it's '7'.  I want to remove just that character from field calculator.  How do I only remove the second character using python?

I can start by doing !PLSS![5:] and chop it down to 20N0650W0.  I need to be able to get the inside zeros too without using a replace.

Answer (score 5):

You can slice and add the string in the field calculator using the Python parser:

```
!column![6:7] + !column![8:9] + !column![10:12] + !column![13:14]
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I was adding them together several different times. I was using just !Column![:2] + !Column![4:] and then adjusting the number each time to meet my need. The format you have is much more efficient and uses less characters. Thanks!